# JS Calculator not working in wordpress, script worked on old site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This issue has been problematic this week. We're creating a new site as the current one is a bit outdated. The current site has a series of financial calculators that work perfectly.

Upon transferring the scripts and content to the new wordpress site, we get an error which prevents it from working.

The error we get is:

```
    TypeError: document.formc is undefined[Learn More] accounting-calc.js:7:3
recalc_onclick
http://77.104.171.166/~paramo48/grtglobal.com/wp-content/themes/child-theme/js/accounting-calc.js:7:3
onclick
http://77.104.171.166/~paramo48/grtglobal.com/business-financial-calculators/:1:1
```

The script we use is:

```
    /* <![CDATA[ */
var co = new Object;

function recalc_onclick(ctl) {
    if (ctl == '') {
        co.pA1B = eeparseFloatTh(document.formc.pA1B.value);
        co.pA2B = eeparsePercent(document.formc.pA2B.value);
        co.pA3B = eeparseFloat(document.formc.pA3B.value);
        calc(co);
        document.formc.pA4B.value = eedatefmt(fmtdate5, co.pA4B);
        document.formc.pA5B.value = eedatefmt(fmtdate5, co.pA5B);
    };
};
var eeisus = 0;
var eetrue = "TRUE";
var eefalse = "FALSE";
var eedec = ".";
var eeth = ",";
var eedecreg = new RegExp("[.]", "g");
var eethreg = new RegExp(",", "g");
var fmtdaynamesshort = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
var fmtdaynameslong = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
var fmtmonthnamesshort = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
var fmtmonthnameslong = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var fmtstrings = new Array(",", " ", "");
var fmtdate5 = new Array(34, 25, 2);
var fmtdate6 = new Array(34, 25, 0);

function calc(data) {
    var cA1B = data.pA1B;
    var cA2B = data.pA2B;
    var cA3B = data.pA3B;
    var cA4B = (((pmt((((cA2B) / (12))), (((cA3B) * (12))), (cA1B), (0), (0))) * (-1)));
    var cA5B = (((((cA1B) * (cA2B))) / (12)));
    data.pA4B = cA4B;
    data.pA5B = cA5B;
};

function myIsNaN(x) {
    return (isNaN(x) || (typeof x == 'number' && !isFinite(x)));
};

function mod(n, d) {
    return n - d * Math.floor(n / d);
};

function round(n, nd) {
    if (isFinite(n) && isFinite(nd)) {
        var sign_n = (n < 0) ? -1 : 1;
        var abs_n = Math.abs(n);
        var factor = Math.pow(10, nd);
        return sign_n * Math.round(abs_n * factor) / factor;
    } else {
        return NaN;
    }
};

function eeparseFloat(str) {
    str = String(str).replace(eedecreg, ".");
    var res = parseFloat(str);
    if (isNaN(res)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return res;
    }
};

function eeparsePercent(str) {
    var parts = String(str).split('%');
    var tmp = String(parts[0]).replace(eedecreg, ".");
    var res = parseFloat(tmp) / 100;
    if (isNaN(res)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return res;
    }
};

function eedisplayFloat(x) {
    if (myIsNaN(x)) {
        return Number.NaN;
    } else {
        return String(x).replace(/\./g, eedec);
    }
};

function eedisplayScientific(x, nd) {
    if (myIsNaN(x)) {
        return Number.NaN;
    } else {
        var str = String(x.toExponential(nd));
        return str.replace(/\./g, eedec);
    }
};

function eedisplayFloatND(x, nd) {
    if (myIsNaN(x)) {
        return Number.NaN;
    } else {
        var res = round(x, nd);
        if (nd > 0) {
            var str = String(res);
            if (str.indexOf('e') != -1) return str;
            if (str.indexOf('E') != -1) return str;
            var parts = str.split('.');
            if (parts.length < 2) {
                var decimals = ('00000000000000').substring(0, nd);
                return (parts[0]).toString() + eedec + decimals;
            } else {
                var decimals = ((parts[1]).toString() + '00000000000000').substring(0, nd);
                return (parts[0]).toString() + eedec + decimals;
            }
        } else {
            return res;
        }
    }
};

function eedisplayPercent(x) {
    if (myIsNaN(x)) {
        return Number.NaN;
    } else {
        var tmp = (x * 100).toString() + '%';
        return tmp.replace(/\./g, eedec);
    }
};

function eedisplayPercentND(x, nd) {
    if (myIsNaN(x)) {
        return Number.NaN;
    } else {
        return eedisplayFloatND(x * 100, nd) + '%';
    }
}

function eeparseFloatTh(str) {
    str = String(str).replace(eethreg, "");
    str = String(str).replace(eedecreg, ".");
    var res = parseFloat(str);
    if (isNaN(res)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return res;
    }
};

function eedisplayFloatNDTh(x, nd) {
    if (myIsNaN(x)) {
        return Number.NaN;
    } else {
        var res = round(x, nd);
        if (nd > 0) {
            var str = String(res);
            if (str.indexOf('e') != -1) return str;
            if (str.indexOf('E') != -1) return str;
            var parts = str.split('.');
            var res2 = eeinsertThousand(parts[0].toString());
            if (parts.length < 2) {
                var decimals = ('00000000000000').substring(0, nd);
                return (res2 + eedec + decimals);
            } else {
                var decimals = ((parts[1]).toString() + '00000000000000').substring(0, nd);
                return (res2 + eedec + decimals);
            }
        } else {
            return (eeinsertThousand(res.toString()));
        }
    }
};

function eedisplayPercentNDTh(x, nd) {
    if (myIsNaN(x)) {
        return Number.NaN;
    } else {
        return eedisplayFloatNDTh(x * 100, nd) + '%';
    }
}

function eeinsertThousand(whole) {
    if (whole == "" || whole.indexOf("e") >= 0) {
        return whole;
    } else {
        var minus_sign = "";
        if (whole.charAt(0) == "-") {
            minus_sign = "-";
            whole = whole.substring(1);
        };
        var res = "";
        var str_length = whole.length - 1;
        for (var ii = 0; ii <= str_length; ii++) {
            if (ii > 0 && ii % 3 == 0) {
                res = eeth + res;
            };
            res = whole.charAt(str_length - ii) + res;
        };
        return minus_sign + res;
    }
};

function eedatefmt(fmt, x) {
    if (!isFinite(x)) return Number.NaN;
    var tmp = 0;
    var res = "";
    var len = fmt.length;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < len; ii++) {
        if (fmt[ii] > 31) {
            res += fmtstrings[fmt[ii] - 32];
        } else {
            switch (fmt[ii]) {
                case 2:
                    res += eemonth(x);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tmp = eemonth(x);
                    if (tmp < 10) {
                        res += "0";
                    };
                    res += tmp;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    res += fmtmonthnamesshort[eemonth(x) - 1];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    res += fmtmonthnameslong[eemonth(x) - 1];
                    break;
                case 6:
                    res += eeday(x);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    tmp = eeday(x);
                    if (tmp < 10) {
                        res += "0";
                    };
                    res += tmp;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    res += fmtdaynamesshort[weekday(x, 1) - 1];
                    break;
                case 9:
                    res += fmtdaynameslong[weekday(x, 1) - 1];
                    break;
                case 10:
                    tmp = year(x) % 100;
                    if (tmp < 10) {
                        res += "0";
                    };
                    res += tmp;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    res += year(x);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    res += hour(x);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    tmp = hour(x);
                    if (tmp < 10) {
                        res += "0";
                    };
                    res += tmp;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    tmp = hour(x) % 12;
                    if (tmp == 0) {
                        res += "12";
                    } else {
                        res += tmp % 12;
                    };
                    break;
                case 15:
                    tmp = hour(x) % 12;
                    if (tmp == 0) {
                        res += "12";
                    } else {
                        if (tmp < 10) {
                            res += "0";
                        };
                        res += tmp;
                    };
                    break;
                case 16:
                    res += minute(x);
                    break;
                case 17:
                    tmp = minute(x);
                    if (tmp < 10) {
                        res += "0";
                    };
                    res += tmp;
                    break;
                case 18:
                    res += second(x);
                    break;
                case 19:
                    tmp = second(x);
                    if (tmp < 10) {
                        res += "0";
                    };
                    res += tmp;
                    break;
                case 21:
                case 22:
                    if (hour(x) < 12) {
                        res += "AM";
                    } else {
                        res += "PM";
                    };
                    break;
                case 23:
                    res += eedisplayFloat(x);
                    break;
                case 24:
                    tmp = fmt[++ii];
                    res += eedisplayFloatND(x, tmp);
                    break;
                case 25:
                    tmp = fmt[++ii];
                    res += eedisplayFloatNDTh(x, tmp);
                    break;
                case 26:
                    res += eedisplayPercent(x);
                    break;
                case 27:
                    tmp = fmt[++ii];
                    res += eedisplayPercentND(x, tmp);
                    break;
                case 28:
                    tmp = fmt[++ii];
                    res += eedisplayPercentNDTh(x, tmp);
                    break;
                case 29:
                    tmp = fmt[++ii];
                    res += eedisplayScientific(x, tmp);
                    break;
            };
        };
    };
    return res;
};

function leap_gregorian(year) {
    return ((year % 4) == 0) && (!(((year % 100) == 0) && ((year % 400) != 0)));
}
var GREGORIAN_EPOCH = 1721425;

function gregorian_to_jd(year, month, day) {
    return (GREGORIAN_EPOCH - 0) + (365 * (year - 1)) + Math.floor((year - 1) / 4) + (-Math.floor((year - 1) / 100)) + Math.floor((year - 1) / 400) + Math.floor((((367 * month) - 362) / 12) + ((month <= 2) ? 0 : (leap_gregorian(year) ? -1 : -2)) + day);
}

function jd_to_gregorian(jd) {
    var wjd, depoch, quadricent, dqc, cent, dcent, quad, dquad, yindex, year, yearday, leapadj;
    wjd = Math.floor(jd);
    depoch = wjd - GREGORIAN_EPOCH - 1;
    quadricent = Math.floor(depoch / 146097);
    dqc = mod(depoch, 146097);
    cent = Math.floor(dqc / 36524);
    dcent = mod(dqc, 36524);
    quad = Math.floor(dcent / 1461);
    dquad = mod(dcent, 1461);
    yindex = Math.floor(dquad / 365);
    year = (quadricent * 400) + (cent * 100) + (quad * 4) + yindex;
    if (!((cent == 4) || (yindex == 4))) {
        year++;
    }
    yearday = wjd - gregorian_to_jd(year, 1, 1);
    leapadj = ((wjd < gregorian_to_jd(year, 3, 1)) ? 0 : (leap_gregorian(year) ? 1 : 2));
    var month = Math.floor((((yearday + leapadj) * 12) + 373) / 367);
    var day = (wjd - gregorian_to_jd(year, month, 1)) + 1;
    return new Array(year, month, day);
}

function eeday(serial_number) {
    if (!isFinite(serial_number)) return Number.NaN;
    if (serial_number < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (serial_number > 60) serial_number--;
    var res = jd_to_gregorian(serial_number + 2415020);
    return res[2];
};

function hour(serial_number) {
    if (!isFinite(serial_number)) return Number.NaN;
    var res = Math.floor((serial_number - Math.floor(serial_number)) * 86400 + 0.5);
    return Math.floor(res / 3600);
}

function minute(serial_number) {
    if (!isFinite(serial_number)) return Number.NaN;
    var res = Math.floor((serial_number - Math.floor(serial_number)) * 86400 + 0.5);
    return Math.floor(res / 60) % 60;
};

function eemonth(serial_number) {
    if (!isFinite(serial_number)) return Number.NaN;
    if (serial_number < 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (serial_number > 60) serial_number--;
    var res = jd_to_gregorian(serial_number + 2415020);
    return res[1];
};

function second(serial_number) {
    if (!isFinite(serial_number)) return Number.NaN;
    var res = Math.floor((serial_number - Math.floor(serial_number)) * 86400 + 0.5);
    return res % 60;
};

function weekday(serial_number, return_type) {
    if (!isFinite(return_type) || !isFinite(serial_number)) return Number.NaN;
    if (return_type < 1 || return_type > 3) return Number.NaN;
    var res = Math.floor(serial_number + 6) % 7;
    switch (Math.floor(return_type)) {
        case 1:
            return res + 1;
        case 2:
            return (res + 6) % 7 + 1;
        case 3:
            return (res + 6) % 7;
    };
    return "hej";
};

function year(serial_number) {
    if (!isFinite(serial_number)) return Number.NaN;
    if (serial_number < 1) {
        return 1900;
    }
    if (serial_number > 60) serial_number--;
    var res = jd_to_gregorian(serial_number + 2415020);
    return res[0];
};

function pmt(rate, nper, pv, fv, type) {
    if (rate == 0) {
        return -pv / nper;
    } else {
        var pvif = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper);
        var fvifa = (Math.pow(1 + rate, nper) - 1) / rate;
        var type1 = (type != 0) ? 1 : 0;
        return ((-pv * pvif - fv) / ((1 + rate * type1) * fvifa));
    }
};
/* ]]> */
```

and the content is:

```
    <form id="formc" method="post" action="" class="calc normal">
<noscript><p>Your browser does not support Javascript or has Javascript disabled.<br />Our calculators will not work without it.</p><p>If you want to enable Javascript but are unsure of how to do it, visit our <a href="/site_help/index.php">website help page</a></p></noscript>
<p>See how much you can afford to borrow...</p>

<fieldset><legend><strong>Calculator</strong></legend>
<p><label for="pA1B">Amount of loan</label><span>£</span><input name="pA1B" id="pA1B" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloatNDTh(eeparseFloatTh(this.value),0);recalc_onclick('pA1B')" value="" type="text"></p>
<p><label for="pA2B">Interest rate</label><span>%</span><input name="pA2B" id="pA2B" onblur="this.value=eedisplayPercentND(eeparsePercent(this.value),2);recalc_onclick('pA2B')" value="" type="text"></p>
<p><label for="pA3B">Term in years</label><span> </span><input name="pA3B" id="pA3B" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloat(eeparseFloat(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA3B')" value="" type="text"></p>
<p class="formresult"><label for="pA4B">Monthly payment</label><span>£</span><input name="pA4B" tabindex="-1" id="pA4B" value="Result" readonly="readonly" type="text"></p>
<p class="formresult"><label for="pA5B">Interest only</label><span>£</span><input name="pA5B" tabindex="-1" id="pA5B" value="Result" readonly="readonly" type="text"></p>
<p><button type="button" name="xl_update_bottom" onclick="recalc_onclick('')">Calculate</button><button type="button" name="xl_reset_bottom" onclick="reset_onclick('')">Reset</button></p>
</fieldset>
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
function reset_onclick(x){document.formc.reset();postcode();recalc_onclick('');};function postcode(){};function eequerystring(){var querystring=document.location.search;if(querystring.length>0){variables=(querystring.substring(1)).split("&");var variable;var key;var value;for(var ii=0;ii<variables.length;ii++){variable=variables[ii].split("=");key=unescape(variable[0]);value=unescape(variable[1]);if(document.formc[key]!=null){document.formc[key].value=value;}}}}function initial_update(){postcode('');eequerystring();recalc_onclick('');}
/* ]]> */</script>
</form>
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I've yet to solve it.

At first I thought formc was a typo but it's the exact same on the original site where it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the name attribute on the form.

```js
console.log(document.formc)
```

```html
<form id="formc" name="formc">
</form>
```